Excel - How to reference a column on another sheet by header title
This is probably a very simple question. We export a fair amount of data from our CRM but only certain columns are relevant. What's the most easy way to populate the 'Relevant Columns' tab from the example data tab? We want to find by the matching header and not using a column number.
Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use the FILTER function to get such a list.
Let's say you want to grab the columns named Name, Phone Number, and Address from the example data Sheet. You can put this formula in the first cell in the Relevant Columns Sheet:
=IF(FILTER('example data'!A:Z, ('example data'!A1:Z1 = "Name") + ('example data'!A1:Z1 = "UPC") + ('example data'!A1:Z1 = "Time")) = 0, "", FILTER('example data'!A:Z, ('example data'!A1:Z1 = "Name") + ('example data'!A1:Z1 = "UPC") + ('example data'!A1:Z1 = "Time")))
This should auto-populate all the rows from the columns matching those 3 provided coulmn headers.
